# How to show Prev Week, Previous Month, YTD in the same table in tableau?

Tags: compiler-errors, tableau-api, datediff, tableau-desktop

I am trying to get the below table in `Tableau`.

| week XX (previous week) | Month X (prev.Month) | YtD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20,000 | 100,000 | 400,0000 |

I am trying to compare the previous week with the prev month. So far I have got the following:

Firstly, I got the day on which the full week ended on, i.e., Sunday as per below

```
(MAX(IF DATEPART('weekday',DATE([Order Date & Time]))=1 and date([Order Date & Time]) <TODAY() 
then DATE([Order Date & Time])
```

END))

Next I am trying to get the `Sales - Last full week` using the following:

`IF DATEDIFF('week',DATE([Order Date & Time]),[Last Complete Sunday]) = 0 THEN COUNTD([Sales]) END`

I am getting the following error: `Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function`

the problem is in the `datediff()` because when also trying to work it on it's own without the IF it still gives me same error. I cannot understand why because I am converting `[Order Date & Time]` to Date and `Last Complete Sunday` is a date.

As reference used: https://onenumber.biz/blog-1/2021/6/8/how-to-compare-last-full-week-to-
previous-full-week-in-tableau
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by putting your IF statement INSIDE the COUNT.

```
COUNTD(
 IF DATEDIFF('week',DATE([Order Date & Time]),[Last Complete Sunday]) = 0 THEN [Sales] END
)
```

If it doesn't match the if statement it will return NULL and will not be in your distinct count.